# Regex + Convert line of numbers separated by white space into array

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to convert a string that contains multiple numbers, where each number is separated by white space, into a double array.

For example, the original string looks like:

```
originalString = "50 12.2 30 48.1"
```

I've been using Regex.Split(originalString, @"\s*"), but it's returning an array that looks like:

```
[50
""
12
"."
2
""
...]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If I could mark all three of those below as answers I would...

Comment: People are less worried about who gets the right answer than they are about getting the right answer :) At least I hope so.

Comment: @Icfseth +1, as long as it works.

Comment: @keynesiancross, if you don't use LinqPad, you should.  It makes debugging this sort of thing so much easier. And it's free!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Split(originalString, @"\s+").Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
```

The `Where` returns an `IEnumerable` with the null/whitespace filtered out.  if you want it as an array still, then just add `.ToArray()` to that chain of calls.

The `+` character is necessary because you need a *MINIMUM* of one to make this a correct match.

Comment: When I try this, it splits doubles "ie 24.5" into each of its individual characters (ie 2,4,.,5)...

Comment: Hmm. Gimme a second with linqpad to mess around with this

Comment: ah yes, I did change that.  Another quick question.  That string has one kicking, it contains one "|" character in it.  How can I use regex to replace that (with ideally a white space).  What was killing mine was I was trying to do: Regex.Match(orgString, "|"), but because its a special character it just adds a ton of white spaces (which, is why I thought this method didn't work at first)

Comment: To match special character you must precede them by the antislash (or is it a slash?) "\|" :) Again, you could simply use String.Replace instead. Still think this method is not the fastest (Split + Where + ToArray). But if you still want to work with Regex...

Answer (score 3):

Using this instead

```
originalString.Split(new char[]{'\t', '\n', ' ', '\r'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

No need to rush RegEx everytime :)

Answer (score 2):

What about `string[] myArray = originalString.Split(' ');` 
I don't see the need for a RegEx here..

If you really want to use a RegEx, use the pattern `\s+` instead of `\s*`.
The `*` means zero or more, but you want to split on one or more space character.

Working example with a RegEx:

```
        string originalString = "50   12.2   30 48.1";
        string[] arr = Regex.Split(originalString, @"\s+");

        foreach (string s in arr)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: He said it was split by 'whitespace' so that wouldn't work for new lines, tabs, or otherwise.  He's got the right regex, he just needs to filter out the unuseful stuff.

Comment: I did try this, but unfortunately the number of whitespace characters is not fixed at one... so I would end up with some really weird array...

Comment: If the number of spaces is variable, you should try the overload of string.Split [with StringSplitOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx). Still no need for regex.

Comment: Your example fails if you put any other sort of white space.  The regex is necessary unless you list all possible whitespaces in your `Split` command

Comment: \s is equivalent to '\t' '\n' '\r' ' ', that is not a long list, and considering that RegEx are usually slower than split, I think it is still worth the shot.

Comment: String manipulation like this is usually used at the beginning of the program for input, or during user interaction, where there are typically a lot of other more time consuming things happening. I don't disagree that Split might be better here, but I didn't feel like it was overkill in this particular place.

Comment: @lcfseth: In ASCII `\s` is the same as `[\f\n\r\t\v]` i.e. form feed, line feed, carriage return, horizontal tab, vertical tab. In Unicode it additionally matches `[\x85\p{Z}]` newline, or Unicode general separator.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with `String.Split`, supplying all whitespace characters that you are expecting.

In regular expressions, `\s` is equivalent to `[ \t\r\n]` (plus some other characters specific to the flavour in use); we can represent these through a `char[]`:

```
string[] nums = originalString.Split(
    new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour if you pass `null` as a separator to `String.Split` is to split on whitespace. That includes anything that matches the Unicode `IsWhiteSpace` test. Within the ASCII range that means tab, line feed, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return and space.

Also you can avoid empty fields by passing the `RemoveEmptyEntries` option.

```
originalString = "50 12.2 30 48.1";
string[] fields = originalString.Split(null as char[], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```